# Unable to import FieldValue.arrayUnion

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

I want to append data in array in Firebase Cloud Firestore. for that i am using `FieldValue.arrayUnion`.

I tired these imports but none of them worked

```
from firebase_admin import firestore
firebase_admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion()

AttributeError: module 'firebase_admin.firestore' has no attribute 'FieldValue'
```

```
from google.cloud import firestore
firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion()

AttributeError: module 'firestore' has no attribute 'FieldValue
```

```
from google.cloud import firestore_v1 as firestore
firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion()

AttributeError: module 'google.cloud.firestore_v1' has no attribute 'FieldValue'
```

Wants to know from where I have to import FieldValue

Answer (score 3):

You can either import ArrayRemove and ArrayUnion from Firestore:

```
from google.cloud.firestore import ArrayUnion, ArrayRemove
```

Or use them like so:

```
city_ref = db.collection(u'cities').document(u'DC')

# Atomically add a new region to the 'regions' array field.
city_ref.update({u'regions': firestore.ArrayUnion([u'greater_virginia'])})

# // Atomically remove a region from the 'regions' array field.
city_ref.update({u'regions': firestore.ArrayRemove([u'east_coast'])})
```